# Send emails with asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to implement the functionality that on my page there is an area where users can enter their email with a question and automatically that email reaches a certain email account (mine). So far it always comes from the same person and not from the person who puts your email in that field

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EnviarMail(MandarMailViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Email email = new Email()
                    {
                        From = model.From,
                        Subject = model.Subject,
                        Body = model.Body
                    };

                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                    mm.To.Add(my email);
                    mm.Subject = email.Subject;
                    mm.Body = email.Body;
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
                    mm.From = new MailAddress(email.From);

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(my email, my password);

                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mm);

                return RedirectToAction("EnvioExitoso");
                }catch(Exception error)
                {
                    ViewBag["Error"] = error.Message;
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug what address is in `mm.From = new MailAddress(email.From)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that specifies the account that is sending the email:

```cs
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(my email, my password);
```

If you want the sender email address to be the visitors address, you have to ask them to put their passwords as well to authenticate their accounts, but regardless that most people will not give their passwords, this is not how you should do it!

Below is the recommended way:

- Create an email account just for sending emails from your page e.g. noreply@domain.com
- Create another email just to recieve the emails coming from the page e.g. support@domian.com
- Keep the users email address in the CC so they receive a copy of the email and feel confident that the message was received on your side as well, and on the other side you can see that address in the CC as well.